# Why acquire a lock in a release operation

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

In the context of creating a monitor to manage access to a single resource, my professor gave us this code:

```java
private final Lock monitor;       
private final Condition nonBusy; 
private boolean busy;             

// acquire resource
public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
    monitor.lock();     
    try {   
        while(busy)
            nonBusy.await();            
        busy = true;    
    } finally {
        monitor.unlock();   
    }
}

// release the previously acquired resource 
public void release() {
    monitor.lock();
    try {
        busy = false;       
        nonBusy.signal();   
    } finally {
        monitor.unlock();
    }
}
```

Why the unlock in the end of the `acquire` operation and the lock in the start of release `operation`?
If I just acquired access to the resource, why release the lock I have for it?

Comment: What do you consider _the resource_ here? Why?

Comment: It's not specified. I presume the monitor.lock() and monitor.unlock() would be there, even if the type of resource changed. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Let me rephrase: what's the critical section?

Comment: The code inside the `try` block

Comment: Which, if you remove all the locking mechanisms, is just `busy`. So you acquired access to the resource, you used it, now you're done with it, so you release access.

Comment: What's the point of getting access to a resource if I'm not going to do anything with it? Shouldn't it be like this: `acquire()` -> do something with the resource -> `release()` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's how'd you write the code: `instance.acquire(); criticalSection(); instance.release();` Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Because in that situation (with the lock() and unlock() in the acquire()), when I performed `criticalSection()` I would not have the lock to the resource

Comment: You need to distinguish between the critical section that's used to implement this acquire/release API and the critical section that this API will protect. When you call `acquire`, it sets `busy` to `true` so all other calls to `acquire` will block.

Comment: And how would I manage that only one thread has possession of the resource?

Comment: There's nothing else for you to manage. Like I said, when you (one of your threads) calls `acquire`, it can then do whatever it wants. Any other calls (from other threads) to `acquire` will block.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are using a `Lock`, a boolean flag, and a condition variable to implement the equivalent of a `Lock`. You are correct in thinking that it is entirely redundant. I think your professor is just giving you an exercise to show the correct way to wait for a condition, and the correct way to signal one. Could have been a little more creative with coming up with a *reason* to wait, and a *reason* to signal, but whatever. What's important is the *pattern* that is embodied by those `acquire()` and `release()` functions.

Note that it's *not* an example of how locks really are implemented at the operating system level because it's missing the notion of a *wait set*. That is, the set of threads that are waiting to acquire any given lock, the set of threads that are waiting to be awakened by a `condition.signal()` call, the set of threads that are waiting for a CPU to run on, etc.